# IF OR Statements which always evaluate to TRUE

Tags: vb.net

Recently I found an error which was due to the way I constructed an IF OR statement.

The original statement:

```
If a = 1 OR 2 OR 3 Then 
  `Execute code 1`
`Else if a = 4 OR 5 OR 6 Then` 
  `Execute code 2`
`Else`
  `Do nothing`
```

The corrected code:

```
If a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 3 Then 
  `Execute code 1`
`Else if a = 4 OR a = 5 OR a = 6 Then` 
  `Execute code 2`
`Else`
  `Do nothing`
```

So, the issue was the first part of the IF statement would always evaluate true regardless of the value of a, because it also evaluates the boolean value of the number 2, which is true. So simply spelling out that each number should be compared to the value of a fixes that issue.

My questions are:
1. When using an if statement and you have a comparative operation ( if a =1) followed  by "OR 2", in what situation would you actually want to look at the boolean value of the number versus comparing the number against the value of the previously referenced variable?

2. Is there a way to identify if statements present in the code which will logically ALWAYS be true (and probably have a error)?

Edit: the_lotus pointed out that the boolean value of each number was not being evaluated but bitwise operations were performed between all the values and then a boolean evaluation was performed on the result. In this particular case it may be possible for it to evaluate either true or false depending on the value of a, though I am still interested in identifying if statements which always evaluate true.

Comment: turn on option strict?

Comment: I don't think it did what you think. It think it did: Is "a" equal to 1? Take the result, convert to integer, do bitwise or 2, do bitwise or 3. Take the result, convert to Boolean.

Comment: Ctznkane525, even with option strict on aren't you allowed to evaluate the boolean value of an integer? And since "2" isn't a variable but does have a boolean value and can be evaluated an error wouldn't be thrown up, right?

Comment: the_lotus, I think you are right that it was doing bitwise operations. My bad, I guess that means that it may be possible for it to evaluate as false depending on the value of a? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators

Comment: @james my point is that you would have had a compile error...which is always better than getting unexpected behavior at runtime

Comment: @James with Option Strict on your first If statement would generate red squiggles. A compile time error is always preferable to a runtime error.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 and Mary, I just went back and opened up the project and ran the first example with option strict ON. No red lines, no compile error. Option strict does not help in this case because no undefined variables are being used, the "2" or "3" are integers and not variables. Go ahead and try "if 1 then" with option strict on and see if it throws "1" up as an undefined variable.

Comment: i wouldn't have expected an undefined variable...but instead an issue converting integer to boolean...because its a narrowing cast

Comment: @Ctznkane525, huh interesting but it still doesn't throw up an error. Could this be because the conversion is occurring within the if statement and the converted value is never assigned to a variable? or it's not really converting it to a boolean value at all and just using the default boolean value of the resulting number?

Comment: when i turn on option strict in visual studio and then put a statement like that - i see this 
Error BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'Boolean'...odd that you do not see that

Comment: Can you post what you ran? You are running in VB.NET inVisual Studio? Imgur link of what I ran, showing no errors and option strict on. https://imgur.com/a/7hl8sSQ

Answer (score 0):

As per your *Edit*, since you want to check if the value of A falls within a range, what you could do is store the ranges as an array and perform IndexOf to see if the value of A is in the collection.

Here is a quick example:

```
Dim a As Integer = 4
Dim collection1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}
Dim collection2() As Integer = {4, 5, 6}

If Array.IndexOf(collection1, a) > -1 Then
    Console.WriteLine("a = 1, 2, or 3")         
ElseIf Array.IndexOf(collection2, a) > -1 Then
    Console.WriteLine("a = 4, 5, or 6")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("a is not a value between 1-6")
End If
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3ckcd)

Comment: Thanks David, for larger numbers of cases that would definitely be preferable to my current solution of a = 1 OR a = 2 OR  a = 3, etc.

Comment: @David `If collection1.Contains(a) Then` might make things easier to read here.

Comment: i think you could inline it Array.IndexOf(New Integer(){1, 2, 3}, a) > -1